# Displaying specific Enum Values in a Dropdown in Asp.Net Mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu, enums

I have an `Enum Class` with 4 `statuses` which are `Created`, `Dispatched`, `Delivered` and `Delayed` in  that respective order.

Currently, all 4 of these appear in the `dropdown` on my `Edit Delivery page`.

What I want is, if my `status` is `Created` then I should **ONLY** be able to change it to `Dispatched`, if my `status` is `Dispatched` I should **ONLY** be able to change it to `Delivered` or `Delayed`, and if my `status` is `Delayed` I should **ONLY** be able to change it to `Dispatched` or `Delivered`.

This should all happen on my `Edit Delivery page`. You'll also notice that I don't want `Created` in either of the lists above as I only require it in `Create Delivery`.

So, essentially  I want to achieve is when my `delivery status` is set to `Created`, I should only see Dispatched in my Enum Dropdown when I wish to Edit that Delivery. Similarly for Dispatched, if my status is set to dispatched then I only want to see `Delivered` or `Delayed`. Same for `Delayed`, I only want to see `Dispatched` and `Delivered`.

I'm fairly new to MVC and if anyone can suggest a solution for this, I'll greatly appreciate it!

Please let me know if any additional code is required and I will add it to the question.

Enum Class:

```
public enum Status
{
    Created, Dispatched, Delivered, Delayed
}
```

Delivery View Model:

```
public class DeliveryVM
{
    public int? ID { get; set; }
    public Status Status { get; set; }
}
```

Delivery Edit View:

```
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Status, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.Status, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @id="dropdown" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Status, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `EnumDropDownListFor()` method will generate options for each item in the enum. Instead you need to use the `DropDownListFor() method.

Add an additional property to you view model for the `SelectList`

```
public class DeliveryVM
{
  public int? ID { get; set; }
  [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select the status")]
  public Status Status { get; set; }
  public SelectList StatusList { get; set; } // add this      
}
```

Then in you GET method, build the options you need based on the existing `Status`. Note you only need to build a list of `string` representing the enum values because the `DefautModelBinder` will convert the posted `string`value to the corresponding `enum` value when you post.

```
Delivery delivery = // get your data model
DeliveryVM model = new DeliveryVM
{ 
  ID = ... // set other properties based on data model
};
// Build list of options basd on current status
List<string> options = new List<string>();
if (delivery.Status == HealthHabitat.Models.Status.Created)
{
  model.Status = HealthHabitat.ViewModels.Status.Dispatched; // its the only choice so set as the default selection
  options.Add(HealthHabitat.ViewModels.Status.Dispatched.ToString());
}
else if (delivery.Status == HealthHabitat.Models.Status.Dispatched)
{
  options.Add(HealthHabitat.ViewModels.Status.Delivered.ToString());
  options.Add(HealthHabitat.ViewModels.Status.Delayed.ToString());
}
else if (delivery.Status == HealthHabitat.Models.Status.Delayed)
{
  options.Add(HealthHabitat.ViewModels.Status.Dispatched.ToString());
  options.Add(HealthHabitat.ViewModels.Status.Delivered.ToString());
}
model.StatusList = new SelectList(options);
return View(model);
```

And in the view

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Status, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Status, Model.StatusList, "Please select",  new { @class = "form-control" }) // unclear why you are changing the id attribute?
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Status, new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

In the POST method, the selected value will be correctly bound to the `Status` property of your view model

Side note: Not clear what you what to do when the current status is `Delivered` (perhaps not render any control?) and if the current status is `Created` you only allow one choice (`Dispatched`) so it seems unnecessary to render a control in that case also.

Comment: Hmm, I think the `Status` in the ViewModel is conflicting with `Status` in the Model. I applied this to status `HealthHabitat.ViewModels.Status.Dispatched` and I tried this `HealthHabitat.Models.Status.Dispatched`  but neither work. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have 2 different enums (one for the data model and one for the view model)?

Comment: Ah, Now I remember you previous question. I have updated the answer with what I think you need based on your use of 2 separate enums.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use a custom select list instead of using `EnumDropDownListFor()` helper method.

First define a strategy to get the next respective list of collection. See this  class `StrategicStatesExtension` below that can give you respective list of states as you defined. Class is defining extension methods so that you can use the method in fluent style. **Note:** Keeping the current status in the next possible statuses to show in the form as default selected item.

```
public static class StrategicStatesExtension
{
    public static Status[] Created
    {
        get
        {
            return new [] { Status.Created, Status.Dispatched };
        }
    }

    public static Status[] Dispatched
    {
        get
        {
            return new [] { Status.Delayed, Status.Delivered, Status.Dispatched };
        }
    }

    public static Status[] Delayed
    {
        get
        {
            return new [] { Status.Delivered, Status.Dispatched, Status.Delayed };
        }
    }

    public static Status[] GetAssociatedValidStatus(this Status currentStatus)
    {
        switch (currentStatus)
        {
            case Status.Created:
                return Created;
            case Status.Dispatched:
                return Dispatched;
            case Status.Delayed:
                return Delayed;
            case Status.Delivered:
                return Status.Delivered;
            default:
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Invalid current state received.");
        }
    }

    public static List<SelectListItem> ToDropDownList(this Status[] sourceStates)
    {
        List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();

        foreach (var item in sourceStates)
        {
            items.Add(
                new SelectListItem { 
                        Value = item.ToString("d"), // Value of enum (short)
                        Text = item.ToString() // Name of enum
                });
        }

        return items;
    }
```

The usage of this strategy extension method would be like:

```
public class DeliveryVM
{
    public int? ID { get; set; }
    public Status Status { get; set; }

    public List<SelectListItem> States { get; set; }

    public DeliveryVM()
    {
        // Sample usage: only for demo you need to call this in other method
        // e.g. where your model is being filled with data.
        this.States = Status.GetAssociatedValidStatus().ToDropDownList();    
    }

}
```

Atlast instead of using `@Html.EnumDropDownListFor` you need to build the List with new property States from either ViewData or from ModelProperty

From ViewData:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor("Statuses",
(List<SelectListItem>)ViewData["Statuses"],"value", "text", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @id="dropdown" })
```

From Model property:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor("Statuses",
(model.Statuses,"value", "text", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @id="dropdown" })
```

Comment: Tried this method out as well, and it works, but I decided to go with Stephen's answer above instead. It was based on code he's helped me with before. Thank you though!

Comment: No problem. Glad the problem is solved. :) I'm not a big fan of If..Else ladders so I avoid them as much as possible to increase the readability of code.